# Asp.net membership database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am novice in asp.net and, I have design a website which is having small database (MS sql server), which is working fine on server but for users login, I have given asp.net membership security, which is not working, because its database is still in the app_data file. Now, how can I transfer membership database on my existing website's server.

Answer (score 6):

First you have to setup the SQL Server Database to implement asp.net Membership.
In order to do that you have to execute the aspnet_Regsql.exe found in 
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\\aspnet_regsql.exe
[More information Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x28wfk74.aspx)

Next you have to create the connection strings in your web.config to point to the right database for Membership.

[Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/default.aspx) has an older [Blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/08/25/423703.aspx) that explains the whole process

Answer (score 0):

If you intend on using ASP.NET Membership security and your own database then you need to roll your own Membership class. See [here](http://www.devx.com/asp/Article/29256) for a step by step guide on how to do it.

Comment: You can enable an existing database for the SqlMembershipProvider.